# Configuration of admin roles and user roles

Tags: asp.net, database, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, web

I am trying to enable the system to have admin roles and login membership roles using the asp.net website administration tool but every time i click on the security tab within the admin tool i receive the following error message

There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store.

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: AccessFile is not valid: C:\Users\Christian\Documents\Uni 2013-2014\FinalYearProject\IcarusAirWEB\App_Data\FINALYEAR.accdb

my web config file code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LocalAccessDatabase" connectionString="C:\Users\Christian\Documents\Uni 2013-2014\FinalYearProject\IcarusAirWEB\App_Data\FINALYEAR.accdb" providerName="AccessProfileProvider"/>

  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="AccessMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AccessMembershipProvider"
     type="Samples.AccessProviders.AccessMembershipProvider"
     connectionStringName="LocalAccessDatabase"
     enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
     enablePasswordReset="false"
     requiresUniqueEmail="true"
     requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
     minRequiredPasswordLength="1"
     minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
     applicationName="SampleSite"
     hashAlgorithmType="SHA1"
     passwordFormat="Hashed"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" defaultProvider="AccessRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="LocalAccessDatabase" applicationName="IcarusAir"
          name="AccessRoleProvider" type="Samples.AccessProviders.AccessRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>



    <authentication mode="Forms"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

I also have some other files in my app data

How do I prevent getting this error message and enable the use of the admin roles and user roles

Comment: Is your connection string accurate?  Access DB's normally use the `System.Data.OleDb` for the provider with a connection string in the format `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=[accdb file path]`

Comment: Your connectionString is not OK. Please refer to this URL: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Answer (score 0):

The first place I would recommend you look is the permission settings for the directory that holds your database, to ensure your IIS user can access it.

1. Right click on the directory,
2. Click 'Security' in the context menu,
3. Click "Edit" in the modal popup to edit permissions
4. Click "Add" in the 2nd modal popup
5. Enter "Everyone" in the multiline textbox in the 3rd modal popup, click "OK"
6. Click "Everyone" in the 2nd modal, and make sure "Read & Execute" is selected in the lower permissions group (allow column)
   and all the available checkboxes below it are checked.
7. Click OK in second modal
8. Click OK in the first modal

This opens your permissions almost as wide as you can go.

The second thing you need to check for is that you actually have the user management schema in your access DB.  Per Kris, this can be a bitch: http://blog.krisvandermast.com/UsingAccessInsteadOfSQLServerForYourASPNETApplicationServices.aspx

Once you can verify permissioning and schema presence are not factors, it should help isolate the problem to configuration in your web.config file.